# TypeScript complaining that rc-tree Tree doesn't have a treeData prop

Tags: typescript, react-component

In my react component has the following code from [react-component/tree](https://github.com/react-component/tree),

```
import Tree from 'rc-tree';
...
<Tree
    className="treeThingy"
    treeData={myTreeData}
/>
```

**This works, but** typescript is complaining that the `treeData` props doesn't exsist on Tree with the following,

> Property 'treeData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2322)

Is this a problem with my code, the rc-tree code, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems more an issue with [`@types/rc-tree`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/rc-tree/index.d.ts) type declarations, not the library. `TreeProps` is missing the `treeData` props, but the library has it.

From the version 3, it seems that `react-component/tree` will include types in the package itself, without relaying on the DefinitelyTyped package.

Comment: looks like you are right.  I just added `treeData?(foo: any);` to the `@types/rc-tree.d.ts` file and the warning went away.  I'll open a ticket with rc-tree.  thanks.

Comment: There is a [PR-36494](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/36494) on definitlyTyped that was closed without being completed.  It looks like version 3 is a much better solution.